# MSSQL show only 15 min interval data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database which measures every minute, this value is the current flow at that time. But I only want to show the measurements every 15 min in a query. So instead I only want to see the value of the RecDate on 9:00, 9:15 etc. I have tried to use, datediff but then I couldn't see what the RecDate was between the values and it would add them up in that timeframe. I tried also some other things, but I think I maybe have used the wrong approach.

I currently have this piece of code, to see the total flow.

```
SELECT rv.RecDate, sum(rv.Value_num) as TotalSUM
FROM         dbo.Channels c INNER JOIN
                          (SELECT     rv.*, TRY_CONVERT(numeric(20, 4), rv.Value) AS value_num, (LEFT(TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0), rv.Timestamp), 16)) AS RecDate
                            FROM          dbo.RecordedValues rv) rv ON c.SourceId = rv.SourceId AND c.Id = rv.ChannelId
WHERE     
(c.Tag LIKE N'%1%'
OR c.Tag LIKE N'%2%'
OR c.Tag LIKE N'%3%'
OR c.Tag LIKE N'%4%')
AND Timestamp BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
Group BY rv.RecDate
```

This gives these values in my table.

```
RecDate             TotalSum
2017-09-20 10:02|   900
2017-09-20 10:03|   1000
2017-09-20 10:04|   950
2017-09-20 10:05|   975
2017-09-20 10:06|   960
etc.
```

How can I get this?:

```
RecDate             TotalSum
2017-09-20 10:00|   900
2017-09-20 10:15|   930
2017-09-20 10:30|   960
2017-09-20 10:45|   950
2017-09-20 11:00|   100
etc.
```

Comment: Hint: `DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '2000-01-01', RecDate) / 15 * 15, '2000-01-01')`.

Comment: Where do I use it in my statement? In my where? I am trying to understand what it does.

Comment: The expression "rounds" the date to a whole 15 minute interval. If you `GROUP BY` it, you will summarize 15-minute periods. (I'm not clear whether that's what you want here, but it's a useful thing to remember regardless.) If you compare it against `RecDate`, you will only get back `RecDate`s that are whole multiples of 15 minutes.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now. I will keep it in mind, because I am probably going to need something like that to later, thanks! But what I actually wanted, is that I only shows the measurement which is done every 15 min. And only that value. But it worked with this:  `datepart(minute,timestamp)%15=0`. Now only see the measurement every 15 min in the table instead of every min!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use datepart like below  to get only 15 minute interval

```
datepart(minute,timestamp)%15=0
```

you also can use a [numbers](http://dataeducation.com/you-require-a-numbers-table/) table to prepopulate  a table like below

```
select DATEADd(MI,number,
Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))),Number
from numbers
where number%15=0
```

which would give me below result

```
 2017-09-21 00:00:00.000
    2017-09-21 00:15:00.000
    2017-09-21 00:30:00.000
    2017-09-21 00:45:00.000
    2017-09-21 01:00:00.000
    2017-09-21 01:15:00.000
    2017-09-21 01:30:00.000
    2017-09-21 01:45:00.000
```

now you can use joins to get your desired result

```
;with cte
as
(
select DATEADd(MI,number,Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))) as dt
from numbers
where number%15=0
)
,cte1
(
your query
)
select * from cte c
join cte1 c1
on c.dt=c1.datecolumn
```

if you can materialize the result of numbers table(Changing dates as per your need) and create an index ,this may work well

Comment: Thank you! I used the datepart before but in group by, but when I use it in where it worked. Didn't know it was this easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VALUES` in sub query.

```
SELECT
    B.TempCol,
    SUM(B.Value) AS SumValue
FROM
(
    SELECT              
        A.Value,
        CONCAT(CONVERT(DATE, A.RecDate),' ', DATEPART(HOUR, A.RecDate), ':', (SELECT TOP 1 T.Title FROM (VALUES (15, '00'), (30, '15'), (45, '30'), (60, '00')) T(Id, Title) WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, A.RecDate) < T.Id)) TempCol
    FROM 
        YourTable A
) B
GROUP BY    
    B.TempCol
```

Using the table below, the time ranges of the dates are found.

```
(VALUES (15, '00'), (30, '15'), (45, '30'), (60, '00'))
```

Result:

```
2017-09-20 10:02 -> 2017-09-20 10:00
2017-09-20 10:17 -> 2017-09-20 10:15
2017-09-20 10:46 -> 2017-09-20 10:45
```